# jsPdf outputs undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, jspdf

I'm using jsPdf to save my  webpage as pdf

I'm using meteor framework, Here is my code

```
'click .button':function(e)
    {
       var doc = new jsPDF();
         var source = $('#stackoverflow').first();
         var specialElementHandlers = {

         };

         doc.fromHTML(
             source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
             0.5,    // x coord
             0.5,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
             });

         doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');  
         doc.save('test.pdf');
    },
```

My stackoverflow div

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="stackoverflow">
        <a href="" class="button">Run Code</a>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text"  id="stackurl" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Your Stackoverflow ID">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="getData">Get Data</button>
          </form>
          <br><br>
           <hr>
          {{> BasicDetails}}
           <hr>
          {{> UserQuestions}}
            <hr>
          {{> UserAnswers}}   
      </div>
```

For the doc.save('test.pdf'), the error is

`saveas is not defined`

I have added `filesaver.js` to my project which loads on the dom loads, still getting the error, **Do I need to add any other packages `blob.js` or `downloadify.js`**

For doc.output('dataurl')

In the output window I'm getting only '`undefined`

I've downloaded zip file from github and added following files to my project

`jspdf.js,
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js,
jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js,
jspdf.plugin.standard_font_metrics.js`

whatis wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**: With slavo solution I'm not getting the `saveAs`  error but still my data is not showing in pdf ,It is showing `undefined` in pdf file. My div contains charts, Is that the problem?

**Looks like jsPDF have problems with the chrts**

Comment: try putting these files to a folder 'client/compatibility': http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: @imslavko, Now I'm not getting `saveAs` not defined method, but the data in 'stackoverflow` is still not showing, In pdf it is showing `undefined`

Comment: probably some load order issues, read docs how the load order is defined

Comment: try to use <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script> that used in their example: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I got confused trying to hook this up as well, so here's what I found while trying to get jsPDF working on Meteor. Instead of using these files:

`jspdf.js,
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js,
jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js,
jspdf.plugin.standard_font_metrics.js`

Find the following two and put them in your 'client/compatibility' folder as imslako suggested:

`jspdf.min.js
jspdf.source.js`

No idea if that will help with your charts error, but it cleared up the `saveAs` issue for me.